# error in captcha generation {} org.apache.axis.AxisFault: (404)Not Found Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, captcha, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am getting the error in captcha generation {} org.apache.axis.AxisFault: (404)Not Found while generating captcha using webservice.
I am using Springboot 2.6.3 and java 1.8
I have checked that in my maven dependency library folder axis-1.4.jar is presented and in org.apache.axis AxisFault.class file also there.